# How to use laravels map() method recursively?

Tags: laravel, recursion

Is there a way to use the map() method recursively? something like:

```
$collection->map(function ($items, $key) {
    ... some customization ...
    callMapItselfRecursively($items, $key);
    ... some customization ...
});
```

So that I could iterate though a multidimensional collection and customize a new one?

Comment: I'm not 100 % sure of the syntax and can't really check at the moment, so I don't want to make this an answer... but you could probably just make a function first, e.g. `function x($a, $b) { return $a + $b; }` and supply that to the mapping method: `->map('x')` and inside the function x you can iterate over a collection and supply itself.